# How to sort only some elements of a sublist from a nested list in Python 3

Tags: python, sorting, sublist

I have a nested list. For example:

```
data=[['Alan', 8, 4, 5], ['Jog', 10, 1, 2], ['Rhys', 7, 8, 8], ['Sam', 7, 8, 9], ['Tom', 5, 6, 9], ['Tommo', 5, 4, 6]]
```

Now I want to sort the numbers within the sub-lists into descending order and finally arrange the nested list into alphabetical order in Python 3.

So output data should be:

```
[['Alan', 8, 5, 4], ['Jog', 10, 2, 1], ['Rhys', 8, 8, 7], ['Sam', 9, 8, 7], ['Tom', 9, 6, 5], ['Tommo', 6, 5, 4]]
```

where numbers in Rhys, Sam, Tom and Tommo have been reordered into descending order.

Comment: What have *you tried*, and what exactly is the problem with it? Sorting the outer list in alphabetical order by the first element of the inner lists is trivial.

Comment: I can sort the sublists by the names only using for example sort(key=lambda x: x[0], reverse=False) but cannot get the the numbers sorted in numerical order. Sorry Alan sublist should read ['Alan', 8, 5, 4] when outputted.

Answer (score 0):

You can use list comprehensions:

```
[[list[0]] + sorted(list[1:], reverse=True) for list in sorted(data)]
```